# MVVM WPF Datagrid TemplateColumn Combobox Selected Item Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am trying to bind some data to a datagrid using the MVVM pattern with WPF.  I have confirmed that the datagrid is populating and indeed, that the specific value (Gender) is populated.  I've also tried every fix that I could find online (including other questions on this site) that's why I am seeking out an answer here.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Gender" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Things I've tried: Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged", IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True".  Although, I am not a super experienced WPF and MVVM programmer, so it could be something simple that I just don't know about.  My models seem to be working elsewhere and they implement observable/are in observable collections where applicable.

Edit: I got it sorted out.  Here is the code that worked for my issue (in case someone else has a similar problem).

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Gender" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Genders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType = Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: It seems odd that you've added ComboBoxItem elements but also tried to bind the ItemsSource property.  I would remove the ComboBoxItem entries from your XAML and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That's a good point.  That's the result of trying a lot of things.  It seems like when I remove the ComboBoxItem's the ComboBox is blank.  Which might be a symptom of the problem, I think.

Comment: Check that the ItemsSource is binding correctly to your Genders property.  Is it located on the same object as the Gender property?  Can you set a breakpoint inside the getter to see if it's accessed?

Comment: Also, check the Output window in Visual Studio while debugging the project.  Sometimes binding errors will print warnings there but otherwise fail silently.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the getting and it doesn't seem to be getting accessed.  My datagrid is bound to a Dependent property of a patient which is in the view model.  Genders is just a simple  string array that's created in the viewmodel.

Comment: BindingExpression path error: 'Genders' property not found on 'object' ''Dependent' (HashCode=22989384)'. BindingExpression:Path=Genders; DataItem='Dependent' (HashCode=22989384); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') This is the Binding Error I get.  (going to research it myself, but I thought I'd try my best to be responsive.

Comment: Make sure that Genders is a property, not a field, and that it's public.

Comment: It is definitely a property of my view model and is public.  I just need to figure out how to get it to look at my view model instead of Dependent (which is the itemsource for the datagrid and selecteditem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you DataGrid's DataContext is the Patient object, try using a RelativeSource binding to point at the DataGrid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Gender" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.Genders}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: The Patient object doesn't store Genders (it stores a Gender relevant to that Patient).  The Genders are located in the ViewModel class which is a datacontext for my View.  I don't know the way to access that with relative path though.

Comment: Is your view in the same XAML file?  You can use RelativeSource with a different ancestor type (e.g. UserControl), or you can refer directly to named elements using ElementName.

Comment: Yes, it is.  I just don't know what type my datacontext would be.  Here is what it looks like:  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocator}, Path=DependentsViewModel}"

Comment: The AncestorType for the RelativeSource should be your view, not the DataContext.  The DataContext will be part of the binding path (e.g. DataContext.Genders).

Comment: Okay, cool that worked.  I appreciate that, but now my SelectedItem is still not binding and when I pick something for one person in the datagrid it populates to every combobox in the column.